# "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault" in C programming

Tags: c

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  int n ,k, i, j, l;
  double c, s, p, q;
  printf("Sa se dea valoarea n pentru combinari: ");
  if(scanf("%d",n)!=1)
  {
    printf("Date eronate");
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("Sa se introduca k pentru a face numarul de combinari: ");
  if(scanf("%d",k)!=1||k>n)
  {
    printf("Date eronate");
    exit(1);
  }

  s=1;
  p=1;
  q=1;

  for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    s*=i;

  for(j=1;j<=k;j++)
    p*=j;

  for(l=1;l<=(n-k);l++)
    q*=n-k;
  c=s/(p*q);
  printf("%g",c);

  getch();

  return 0;
}
```

This is my program, this program must calculate the combinations from n to k and is giving me that error. What can i do?

Answer (score 2):

```
if(scanf("%d",n)!=1)
```

should be

```
if(scanf("%d",&n)!=1)
//            ^
```

The same applies for later code that sets `k`.

You need to pass the address of any variables you want `scanf` to write to.

As PaulR notes, your compiler is likely to warn you about mistakes like this if you enable warnings (`-Wall` for gcc, `/W4` for MSVC).  Doing this for your program would have reported

> warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 2
>   has type 'int' [-Wformat]

...which would have helped you diagnose the problem yourself.

Comment: +1: and perhaps note that gcc and certain other compilers would have caught this error if only warnings had been enabled...